# Spring data REST advanced resources

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am just implementing the REST endpoints for my app and I am not sure, which way is the best practice.

I am getting all my entities this way

```
@GetMapping("/offers")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<Offer>> getAllOffers(@ApiParam Pageable pageable)
        throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Offers");
        Page<Offer> page = offerService.findAll(pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/offers");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

But what should I do, If I want for example only the offers with some specific projectId.

```
@Query("FROM Offer o WHERE o.project.id = :projectId")
List<Offer> findAllByProject(@Param("projectId") Long projectId);
```

**Q1** How should the REST method for this repository call looks like? What would be the correct mapping path or parameter insertion.

**Q2** What if I want to create more complex query? For example for getting offers based on locality, salary etc.?

I know I can do it somehow, but I am looking for a clean code way. I want to keep my code clean, extensible and sustainable. And **primarily I want to follow the rules of REST**.

Comment: Spring Data REST give built-in [feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.configuring-the-rest-url-path) to do this. More [info](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can inject a bean of your repository type. Spring generates a fully-configured proxy instance and locates it in the context. You are able to specify paths to the operations defined within the repository if it is exported:

   ```
   @RepositoryRestResource(exported = true, path = "path-to-repository")
   ```

   To set the path to an operation, there is the `@RestResource` annotation which you can place over the method:

   ```
   @RestResource(exported = true, path = "operation")
   ```

   By default, it will be available by a `path-to-repository/search/operation`.
2. Write a custom query with the `@Query` and the JPQ language or take more detailed control with native SQL:

   ```
   @Query(value = "...", nativeQuery = true)
   ```

Practically, some operations hardly can be implemented by repositories due to their complexity. It could breed too large default methods which process a few repository methods to produce a desired output.

The solution is creating a pair of controller and service that are going to "copy" and complement repository doings. Fortunately, Spring provides methods to make projection/sort/pagination and other stuff which repositories do out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using swagger annotations (@ApiParam) which I've never used, but in Spring, mark your controller with @RestController if you are not already doing so.

```
@RestController
public class OfferRestController {
.....
```

You can define your endpoints like this - if you're using Spring boot, and have jackson on your classpath, it will take care of the serialisation for you;

```
@GetMapping(value="/offers")
public List<Offer> getAllOffers() {
    return offerService.findAll(pageable);
}

@GetMapping(value="/offers/{location})
public List<Offer> getAllOffers(@PathVariable("location") String location) {
    return offerService.findByLocation(location);
}
```

Great that you know about about JPA repositories, have you met Spring RestRepositories? They expose your queries over REST automatically

```
interface OfferRepository extends CrudRepository<Offer,Long> {
    List<Offer> findByLocation (final String location)
}
```

would expose an endpoint like this;

```
http://localhost:8080/offers/search/findByLocation?location=London
```

You'll need the spring boot starters, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, spring-boot-starter-data-rest and spring-data-rest-hal-browser will allow you to navigate your REST repositories through a browser ([Spring starter guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)).

I'm not brave enough to provide an example(!), but for building more advanced queries you can provide custom implementation with through query [Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)

[edit]

> primarily I want to follow the rules of REST.

You also have @PostMapping, @DeleteMapping, @PutMapping that work like the @GetMapping and map to corresponding HTTP verbs; you would post like this;

```
@PostMapping ("/offers")
public void postSomething (@RequestBody Offer offer) {
    offerService.save (offer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With spring data jpa you can use query methods to compose fairly complex queries. Reference [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/).

Comment: Thats not answer to my question. I know about query methods. I do not know how to create resource/endpoints of them.